# How do I reattach a glass shower door that has come away from the hinge?

Tags: doors, shower, glass

Our shower door has come away from the hinge housing that runs along it's length. It has a rubber seal around the edge of the glass but no other fixings. How do I go about refitting it? I've attached a couple of pictures below, the glass just sits in the fixing but isn't screwed in or anything.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a swinging glass door held to its hinge by nothing but a rubber gasket.  You would think that to be a bad idea, and your experience seems to confirm it.  My suggestion: replace it.  Look for a mechanical connection, bolted on.  [You won't have to look hard.](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=euro+shower+door&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to remove what's left of the plastic/rubber gasket on the glass in picture #2, then find a replacement.

I'd suggest that you look on the door hardware for some sort of manufacturer information, then contact the manufacturer directly and get the replacement gasket from them. You'll also want to get instructions from them on exactly what adhesives (if any) to use to attach the gasket to the door and to attach the door/gasket combo to the hinge strip.

You might be able to find the gasket a few bucks cheaper online somewhere, but coming directly from the manufacturer will ensure that you're getting *exactly* the right one and will help ensure that the door doesn't fall out, hitting your foot or worse, shattering when you're barefoot coming out of the shower.

If you're having trouble finding the manufacturer's name, I'd suggest looking at the top of the black plastic piece that covers the top pivot point. Odds are good that it's marked there, though you may have to remove it and look inside. If you only find some numbers, try entering those into your favorite search engine to see what the hive-mind has to say about them.

Comment: Installation instructions from manufacturer is the best starting point. Most likely that hinge comes apart and there's something in there that clamps the glass to the hinge. A new gasket along with assembling correctly is probably all that's needed.

Comment: Really good point, @PlatinumGoose. The shiny silver of the hinge might be covers that come off to expose some sort of bolt/clamp mechanism to hold the glass. In any case, mfgr instructions would be the place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks like the U-shaped shiny piece snaps into the more rigid non-shiny outer piece. The flexible shiny piece is compressed by the outer channel and the rubber strip grips the glass. It could be difficult to separate the 2 U-channels. Starting from one end you could squeeze the inner channel while prying behind it. Once away from the end you may have to tap in a pointed metal rod as you squeeze along the front. You may end up with a lot of scratches. The manufacturer may sell a fresh unassembled pair of channels.

Comment: To help find the manufacturer use the IMAGES feature of the search engine to look at hundreds of pictures quickly and maybe find one that looks like yours. I do this often to find discontinued or obscure items.

Answer (score 0):

It may have just been glued in. If you look on top of the hinge that's still attached to the wall you'll probably find some screws. If you remove the screws and the grey cap at the top you'll probably be able to remove the shiny slotted vertical tube part that was affixed to the glass.

(The screws may be stainless steel and quite soft, so don't slip the screwdriver. Also, put the plug in / cover the drain so you don't lose the screw if you drop it.)

That'll give you a few more options:

1. The clamping mechanism may now be obvious.
2. It will allow you to confirm if it was glued. In which case I'd clean up both surfaces really well and find a suitable mastik / glue / sealant. Glue the glass and slotted cylinder back together and reassemble.
3. Failing that, at least you now have the parts in your hands and can take it somewhere to have it reconnected.